# Как вводить данные в БД не по коду

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

У меня появилась проблема с заполнение данных в Visual Studio, Windows Form
Всё по стандарту я подключаю БД
Осуществляю её просмотр с помощью компонента DataGridView ну и её заполнение, но я не знаю как избавиться от заполнения полей через код_поля [image: Изображение]

Может кто знает как избавится от этой проблемы?

Comment: сделайте поле типа выпадающего списка и забиндите на него коллекцию

Comment: Хорошо, попробую

Comment: А как  мне это сделать через таблицу ?

Comment: Дайте-ка угадаю. Используется Sql Server, ADO.NET, DataSet, DataTable? Нужно взять данные из _нескольких_ таблиц? Посмотрите ответ [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/ru-RU/3437d394-588b-459f-a26e-998d022ae258/10741099109510801089108311031077108410991081?forum=fordataru).